# How do i Restore the default Text look/quality on my windows?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, display-settings

Ok, This might sound dumb but i wanna know how do i restore the Text look or Text Quality on my Windows 10.
Im not talking about the font but the look/quality of the text. I was trying to install HAXM for android studio and unknowingly i tweaked some settings, after which the quality of the font decreased drastically. I have tried the control panel and settings but for no avail. I cant exactly recall the window in which i tweaked the settings. Below is a screenshot showing the low quality of the text.

[image: The Screenshot]

Comment: If you were following any sort of guide for the HAXM studio install you should be able to refer to it to see what changes you made. Also, you should look for the Adjust ClearType Text Control Panel dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the only way to know for certain what you changed is for you to tell us. We can guess, but we cannot know.

Second, if you followed any sort of guide, you should refer to this to help remind you what you changed.

Third, I suggest opening the Adjust ClearType Text dialog in the Control Panel and using that to adjust your text display settings.

Comment: YES MY MAN! This worked. I tried Fixing The HAXM Months ago. Butt-load of tabs were open in my browser and i was just going through all of them to figure out the solution so i couldn't remember the actual site. Again, thanks for the help though, appreciate it!